# Asynchronous threads in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, visual-c++

We are using Visual Studio 2005 to develop a game (Some of our computers still run Windows 2000, this is the latest version that will run and we can't convert it easily to newer versions anyways) in C++.

Our music composer has written a few short tracks to test the system already, but an issue has arisen:
The game freezes while playing music or sound effects.

While this is not particularly a great issue for SFX, music is a very big problem, since we need it to run in the background.

I figure we can probably create a second thread or process in the background to play the specified track on a loop, but when I search I can't find anything that would work for this, since there needs to be a data transfer (albeit one-way) between the two processes.

The way I see it, we should be able to pass a command to the music process from the main program containing the track number to play - this should be fairly simple, but we've recently moved to C++ and aren't very experienced with it currently.

Thanks for any suggestions.

P.S. Please do not comment on our use of outdated software, we do this for fun and don't plan on putting any money into it at all.

EDIT: For clarity, in case it wasn't clear we are all running Windows and do not plan to port this to any other platform - We're running Visual Studio 2005, but the plan is to begin moving to Visual Studio 2008 or 2010 Ultimate once we can acquire the appropriate discs and software.

The music is done using nothing but the Beep(); command built into the standard Windows header file (windows.h).

We would like to run a secondary process parallel to the main program to allow for background music.

If it turns out that the transfer of data between the two processes is too great an ordeal, would we be able to pass a starting variable to it as the track number when it opens and simply kill it when it's done?

Comment: There are resources on MSDN that describe WIN32's [multithreading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6h8hye8(v=vs.80).aspx) capabilities. Without access to newer C++ features such as the `<thread>` library, you're going to end up having to do a lot of it manually using WIN32 system calls.

Comment: If you are only transferring a track number, just use some atomic int 'trackNum' var, and have the sound thread read it whenever it gets to the end of a track and needs to choose the nest one, (or repeat the same one). If you need to stop it, you could arrange for '-1' to mean 'stop playing and wait on an event for now'.

Comment: Yes, but how would we create the new thread and allow for this? Could you give a simple example?

Comment: If you are using the MFC see:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3w9x78e(v=vs.80).aspx  If you using straight WIn32 see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: What is MFC? We are probably using Win32 - Like I said, this is a mostly console application running with the Borland Graphics Interface for Visual Studio 2005, so this is probably not included.

Comment: "The game freezes while playing music or sound effects" this sounds like the bug you need to find and fix, rather than adding more complexity (and more bugs) with threads and what-not.

Comment: @JesperJuhl it's not a bug....

Comment: It's not a bug - The game stops to run all the Beep(); commands and resumes when it's finished, but we want the music to loop and (preferably) not halt the program temporarily.

Comment: `The game stops to run all the Beep(); commands and resumes when it's finished` -- this means your sound API call is blocking. You will need to find a different sound effect library or API when a non-blocking calls are allowed. Which library are you using now?

Comment: This is done using nothing but the windows.h header - I'm not looking to change the way music is done, just move it to a separate process so they can run parallel to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of Visual Studio, variables declared as volatile will include memory fence operations (unless this option is turned off, it's on by default) , allowing them to be used between threads. Given that, the code could use use a volatile variable for which music track to play. I included  example C code below.

I assume that while playing music, Beep() will not be cpu bound (it doesn't seem to be for Windows XP).

For more accurate timing, timeBeginPeriod() can be used to increase ticker frequency from 64hz (15.625 ms) to 1000hz (1 ms). In the case of Windows XP and maybe Windows 2000, timeBeginPeriod(1) causes the ticker to actually run at 1024hz, while Sleep() and my guess Beep() emulate a 1000hz ticker by adding in 3 extra actual ticks every 128 ticks to end up on a 125 ms boundary. This means that Sleep(1) may take up to almost 2ms occasionally (on the 42, 84, and 125 call).

Note - eventually because of the lack of hardware to communicate with, support for Beep was dropped in Windows Vista and Windows XP 64-Bit Edition. In Windows 7, Beep was rewritten to pass the beep to the default sound device for the session. This is normally the sound card, except when run under Terminal Services, in which case the beep is rendered on the client.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679277(v=vs.85).aspx

Example multi-threaded "beep" code. This code works as expected on Windows XP, using the PC speaker. On Windows 7, it uses the sound card, and there's some silence between notes.

```
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*      mtbeep.c        multi-thread beep demo                          */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include <windows.h>
/* include winmm.lib for timeBeginPeriod */
#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")

#define TRACK0 0
#define TRACK1 1
#define TRACK2 2
#define TRACKX 3                       /* exit thread 1 if trackx */

typedef struct {
    DWORD dwFreq;
    DWORD dwDuration;
}NOTE;

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*      data                                                            */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
static HANDLE   htT1;                   /* thread 1 handle */
static DWORD    dwThreadT1;             /* thread id's (not used) */

static volatile DWORD dwTrack;          /* beep track to play */

/* songs */
static NOTE     anTrack0[4] = {300, 500, 450, 500, 600, 500, 0, 0};
static NOTE     anTrack1[4] = {  0, 250};
static NOTE     anTrack2[4] = {400, 500, 300, 500, 200, 500, 0, 0};
static NOTE     anTrackx[4] = {0, 0};

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*      code                                                            */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
static DWORD    WINAPI Thread0(LPVOID);
static DWORD    WINAPI Thread1(LPVOID);
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*      main                                                            */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
DWORD main(DWORD argc, BYTE **argv)
{
    timeBeginPeriod(1);                 /* set period to 1ms */
    Sleep(128);                         /* wait for it to stabilize */

    /*  create thread */
    htT1 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, Thread1, 0, 0, &dwThreadT1);
    if(!htT1){
        /* createthread failed */
        goto exit0;}
    Thread0((LPVOID)NULL);              /* start Thread 0 */
exit0:
    if(htT1){                           /* close thread */
        dwTrack = TRACKX;
        WaitForSingleObject(htT1, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(htT1);}
    timeEndPeriod(1);                   /* restore period */
    return(0);
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*      Thread0                                                         */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
static DWORD WINAPI Thread0(LPVOID lpvoid)
{
int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        dwTrack = i%3;
        Sleep(5000);
    }
    return 0;
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*      Thread1         beep thread                                     */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
static DWORD WINAPI Thread1(LPVOID lpvoid)
{
NOTE *apTrack[4] = {anTrack0, anTrack1, anTrack2, anTrackx};
NOTE *pTrack = anTrack0;                /* ptr to array of notes */
DWORD cTrack = TRACKX;                  /* current track */
int iNote = 0;                          /* note index */

    while(dwTrack != TRACKX){           /* play a note loop */
        if(cTrack != dwTrack){          /* if song changed */
            iNote = 0;                  /*  start at first note */
            cTrack = dwTrack;           /*  of next song */
            pTrack = apTrack[cTrack];
        }
        if(!pTrack[iNote].dwDuration)   /* if end of song */
            iNote = 0;                  /*  reset note index */
        if(pTrack[iNote].dwFreq)        /* if note play it */
            Beep(pTrack[iNote].dwFreq, pTrack[iNote].dwDuration);
        else                            /* else silence */
            Sleep(pTrack[iNote].dwDuration);
        iNote++;
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: This is very good, but I'm not sure how I'd implement such a solution. 
This was probably the best answer so far, but we're very green at this, so none of us understand what this is at all.

Timing is not a particular issue, the processes (in our minds) should run parallel to each other and not have to run in sync at all except when a command is sent over.

Comment: @FAMICOMASTER - I changed my answer to show an example using Beep() to play "songs".

Comment: Haven't tried it yet, but this seems like it will work. Thank you!